# Simulate more than 2 touches on iPad/iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

Is it possible to simulate more than 2 touches on either the iPad or iPhone simulators?

Holding down the ALT key allows 2 touches but no more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default sim doesn't support more than 2 touches. But there is a 3rd party simulator called iSumulate which supports multi-touch.

Website: http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/
iTunes App Page:  http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/isimulate/id306908756?mt=8